# (jQuery/CSS) Annoying flickering when blur disappears

Tags: jquery, css

I have an effect where a text fades in and go from blur to normal (both at the same time). The annoying bit is that the words in the sentence flickering in the end when the blur is removed completely. I have no idea why this is happening or how it can be removed.

Take a look at the effect here:

```js
// Creates span-elements of the words
var words = $(".sentence").text().split(" ");
$(".sentence").empty();

$.each(words, function(i, v) {
 $(".sentence").append($("<span class='effect'>").text(v));
 $(".sentence").append(' ');
});
 
// The effect
$('.sentence').children('.effect').each(function() {

 var effect = this;
 var filterVal = 'blur(0px)';
    
 setTimeout(function () {
  $(effect).css("opacity", 1);
  $(effect).css("webkitFilter", filterVal);
 }, Math.random() * 3000)
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
  
.sentence {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.effect {
  transition: -webkit-filter 1s linear, opacity 1s linear;
  -webkit-filter:blur(10px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sentence">
  Hi there! Do you know how to remove the glitching?
</div>
```

I have searched a lot and found the solutions below, however, they do not seem to make any difference in my example...

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;

-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Any ideas on solutions? I use Chrome by the way.

Comment: It seems to only happen on initial page load.  Perhaps adding a display: none on body until page loads?

Comment: try display:inline-block to .effect class

Comment: I tried "display: inline-block" without any success, however, adding a "display: none" to the body seems to work okay. The problem though is that the delay messes up another effect on the website. There must be some other way to resolve this :) ... I hope ...